# Is JAVA_OPTIONS boolean case sensitive?

Tags: java, javaoptions

I am trying to set JAVA_OPTIONS to my application

`-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Can I also set it as `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=True` with the capital T? Does the case matter?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, a property must be set to some of the allowed values (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html), and be written **literally**.

Comment: Would it fail to be enabled because of the capital T?

Comment: I couldn't tell. Does some error message show up when you run your program?

Comment: No, it doesn't throw an error message when I run the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the occasion when the difference between being a *good programmer* and being a *good designer* matters:

- A good programmer will make sure that this parametrization (`-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=True`) works in the current environment: For example, if you are using Open JDK 15, you shall browse the source code and you will see that the class `java.net.PlainSocketImpl`, where that parameter is used, delegates on `Boolean.parseBoolean`, which does a case-insensitive parsing.
- A good designer, instead, will make sure to set a parametrization such that **will work on every environment** (Open JDK, Oracle JDK, version 15, future versions, Windows, Linux, etc), by sticking to the [public documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html), which states that only "true" or "false" (or absent) values must be used.

Summarizing: If you are using Open JDK 15, there is no difference between "True" or "true" values, but you cannot be sure that in future versions such difference will matter. I recommend you to stick to the docummented allowed values.

Answer (score 0):

To read boolean system properties, you'd typically use

`Boolean.getBoolean("argument.name");`

Which:

> Returns true if and only if the system property named by the argument
> exists and is equal to the string "true". (**Beginning with version
> 1.0.2 of the JavaTM platform, the test of this string is case *insensitive*.**)

([Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-))

It's really up to the developer (which can also use [System.getProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-) then cast the result to boolean, in his own way), but I'd say for most cases, I'd assume it's case insensitive.